# Мигающая надпись

Tags: java

У меня возник вопрос, ответьте кто может. Можно ли сделать чтобы чтобы при выводе строки,она мигала? Если да, то как? Вот в таком обычном выводе:

```
System.out.print("Привет");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделай таймаут на 1 секунду и через раз запускай:
то : `System.out.print("\rПривет");`
то: `System.out.print("\r           ");`

Первый раз у тебя выведет привет, а во второй переведт каретку в начало строки и затрет пробелами.
А вообще погугли [Вот это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852665/command-line-progress-bar-in-java) [и это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60221/how-to-animate-the-command-line)
**UPD:**
По просьбе трудящихся:

```
 public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        ProgressBarRotating progressBarRotating=new ProgressBarRotating();
        progressBarRotating.start();
    }
    }

class ProgressBarRotating extends Thread {
    boolean showProgress = true;
    public void run() {
        Boolean isVisible = true;
        while (showProgress) {
                   isVisible=!isVisible;
                    if(isVisible){
                System.out.print("\rПривет");
            }
            else
            {
                         System.out.print("\r            ");
            }
            try { Thread.sleep(100); }
            catch (Exception e) {};
        }
    }
}
```

[Выложил сорцы и бинарник](http://dfiles.ru/files/id6rmdm01)

Comment: Это если в текстовом поле,а в консоли как быть?

Comment: System.out.print - доку почитайте6 он какраз выводит текст в консоль, для текстового поля юзайте что нить аля swing и textField подобные классы.

Answer (score 3):

Для Java это не совсем тривиальная задача... хотя бы уже потому, что `System.out` может выводиться куда угодно - хоть смситься или печататься на принтере :) - а там как вы понимаете с морганием туговато будет.

1. Если `System.out` выводится на консоль, который поддерживает стандартные [ANSI коды терминала](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) - то можно сделать мигающую надпись простым вызовом escape последовательностей. Сразу огорчу Win32 не поддерживает ANSI коды :)
2. Есть библиотечка [JCurses](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/), которая по сути представляет инструмент для реализации ANSI подобного терминала средствами Java. Там можно сделать моргание, цвета, курсоры и проч.

**Update**

Если вы еще задаете вопросы типа:

> у меня чисто академический интерес
> можно ли это реализовать. Если кого не
> затруднит напишите пожста код,который
> тупо выводит мигающую надпись. Я думаю
> это будет интересно увидеть не только
> мне)

это означает, паря, что вы ни хрена не понимаете что такое Java. Попробую разжевать ламерским языком: Java это язык программирования не для конкретной оси, а сразу для всех сразу - как грится *write once, use everywhere* или если быть точнее для некой виртуальной (не существующей в природе) машины которую принято называть JVM. В переводе на чайницкий это означает, что поскольку вы пишете для всех осей сразу, то теоретически и практически есть оси которые не поддерживает мигание/моргание в консоли, а раз так то в Java сделать *тупо* мигание/моргание для всех сразу не получится.

Получится:

1. для осей с ANSI терминалами (как расписано выше)
2. или как пацаны ([[@bimawa](/users/10304/bimawa)](/users/10304/bimawa) и [[@BuilderC](/users/4126/builderc)](/users/4126/builderc)) написали приладу для осей для которых `\r` означает возврат каретки без перевода строки
3. или же самому перехватить вывод на консоль и вывести ее в графическое окошечко и там изгалиться как душе угодно (JCurses)

Так что, пересмотрите свое отношение к Java - вы его не понимаете.

Comment: Мне до таких библиотек еще долго! У меня нет конкретной задачи, у меня чисто академический интерес можно ли это реализовать. Если кого не затруднит напишите пожста код,который тупо выводит мигающую надпись. Я думаю это будет интересно увидеть не только мне)

Comment: см. апдейт ответа

Comment: Какая разница насколько я разбираюсь в java? Я начинающий программист и знаю java столько сколько мне достаточно на данный момент. Я решил самостоятельно изучать дальше, чтобы писать более серъезные программы и у меня возник вопрос. Мне интересны разные примеры реализации и я попросил кому не лень пусть напишет или кинет ссылку на самую простую реализацию задачи.

Comment: Закрываю тему как непродуктивную.

Answer (score 2):

Первое, что приходит мне в голову, это создание второго потока, в котором и следует проводить операции, описанные уважаемым [@Bimawa](/users/10304/bimawa). В противном случае Ваша программа только и будет заниматься миганием "ПРИВЕТА".

Comment: Все верно говорите.